# android Map<> how to setText() with key name if object have TRUE value

Tags: android, arraylist, hashmap, google-cloud-firestore

I was getting data from the `firestore` and put it in the `Map<>`.After that, I wanted to show the data which have the true value with `setText` method. But there was problem with I using `List` to store the value to check there are repeat loop or not. So I realize that, the key which have true value are repeating looping as there are `Map<> check` which have size() with 21. So it looping 21 times and repeating put value into the `List`. How can I just loop for 1 time to get all the `key` which have **true** value?

My code at below:

```
private Map<String, Object> check = new HashMap<>();  //declare variable
private List<String> amenityName= new ArrayList<>(); //declare variable

if(check != null){   //check is not null
     for(Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : check.entrySet() ){
                   String key= entry.getKey();
                   Object value = entry.getValue();
                   if(value != null){
                        amenityName.add(key);
                   }
                }
             amenityName.size();   // check the size
}
```

**The data store in Map<> check as picture below:**

[image]

`amenityName.size()` **as picture below:**

[image]

Comment: Please add your database structure, to see the data more clearly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if I get your question right. you want to get the String values which are equal to "true"

you can do this by simply wrapping your `for` the block in an `if` statement

something like this:

```
private Map<String, String> check = new HashMap<>();  //declare variable
private List<String> amenityName= new ArrayList<>(); //declare variable

if(check != null){   //check is not null
     for(Map.Entry<String, String> entry : check.entrySet() ){
                   String key= entry.getKey();
                   String value = entry.getValue();
                   if(value != null && value.equalIgnoreCase("true")){
                        amenityName.add(key);
                   }
                }
             amenityName.size();   // check the size
}
```

**EDIT**

and if you are trying to filter the duplicate keys in the final list you can do so by adding a simple `if` statement:

```
for(Map.Entry<String, String> entry : check.entrySet() ){
                   String key= entry.getKey();
                   String value = entry.getValue();
                   if(value != null && value.equalIgnoreCase("true")){
                        if(!amenityName.contains(key)){
                             amenityName.add(key);
                        }
                   }
                }
```

Comment: No, the question which might i understand that he is getting issue of duplicate values in list. Adding values with true string is not a problem.

Comment: thanks for your try.
but the check that he has done for true string is wrong. thats why i explained my answer in such a way

Comment: you did great.I was just focusing on the real problem he is getting.Appreciated your effort.

Comment: Ya haha, I just forget to check with capital word true, Thank mans

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can find all the keys with value **true** without using for loop. Refer my below example:-

```
   //below is the hash map
    Map<String, Object> check = new HashMap<>();
    check.put("abc",true);
    check.put("zzz","");
    check.put("aaa",true);
    check.put("eee",null);
    check.put("rrr",true);

   //Retain all the pairs in map whose value is true
   check.values().retainAll(Collections.singleton(true));

    //add the filtered map to array list
    List<String> stringList=new ArrayList<>();
    stringList.addAll(check.keySet());

    Log.e("TAG", "onCreate************: "+check.size()+"****"+stringList );
```